# InStr will not find dots in some cases

Tags: excel, vba

I have strings that consist of leading dots followed by a number (for example "..2" or "....4". I want to delete all leading dots and convert the string into a long variable.
So I have written a function that finds leading dots in strings and deletes them. For some reason, the function works for a string like "..2" but will not work for "...3". The `InStr` function will not find "." in "...3".
The strings are read out from a column in a worksheet. They are not formatted in any weird way, I have tried just typing them in manually in a new worksheet without any changes to the default formatting settings, same results.

So I have tried several things. I beleive there must be some error involving character encodings, I cannot figure out how to solve this problem though.
I have tried using a recursive function using InStr to delete the dots and then tried the split function with "." as the delimiter to test my assumption. `Split` has the same problem, works for "..2" but will not work for "...3".
When I debug print the strings that I read out, "...3" seems to be formatted differently than "..2" or ".1". I do not know why.
[here you can see the difference in the formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCYjx.png)

```
Sub Gruppieren()
'read out strings first
'then try to delete the dots
Dim strArr() As String
Dim lngArr() As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

lLastRow = getFirstEmptyRow("A", Tabelle1.Index) 
ReDim strArr(1 To lLastRow)
ReDim lngArr(1 To lLastRow)

For i = 1 To UBound(strArr)
 strArr(i) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
 Debug.Print strArr(i)
 strArr(i) = clearLeadingDots(strArr(i))
 'strArr(i) = splitMeIfYouCan(strArr(i))
 If IsNumeric(strArr(i)) = True Then
  lngArr(i) = CLng((strArr(i)))
  Debug.Print lngArr(i)
 End If
Next i
End Sub
```

'The functions:

```
Function clearLeadingDots(myText As String) As String
 Dim i As Long

 i = InStr(myText, ".")
  If i <> 0 Then
    myText = Right(CStr(myText), Len(myText) - i)
    clearLeadingDots = clearLeadingDots(CStr(myText))
  Else
    clearLeadingDots = CStr(myText)
    Exit Function
  End If
End Function

Function splitMeIfYouCan(myText As String) As String
 Dim myArr() As String
 Dim i As Long
 myArr = Split(myText, ".")

 splitMeIfYouCan = myArr(UBound(myArr))
End Function
```

Edit: The answer was, that three dots were converted into an ellipsis automatically, searching for and eliminating `Chr(133)` did the job.

Comment: Maybe it's changed to ellipsis (...)? Try char(133).

Comment: @EganWolf: I believe you are right. `Chr(133)` finds it :)

Comment: Thank you very much, `Chr(133)` did the job!

Comment: Was browsing through your old/open questions, for this particular one you could also use `RegExp` lib to avoid these functions. Also, you might not need VBA at all as it can be done through a formula.

Comment: @JvdV thank you for your effort! And thanks for telling me about `RegExp`. I have been doing a lot of string comparisons actually and this seems a very useful tool for that purpose. About the formulas: That is a part I really need to work on, making use of those formulas where they already exists, so I do not have to fire up a macro for everything! EDIT: For anyone reading this in the future: Look here for a really good answer explaining regular expressions in Excel VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops